# Downcast in java

Tags: java

I have two classes:

```
public class Parent{
    /* Some Code */
}
public class Child1 extends Parent{
    /* Some Code */
}
public class Child2 extends Parent{
    /* Some Code */
}
```

and iI have a `HashMap<String, Parent>`. Using `com.google.gson.Gson` I have converted this HashMap to Json:

```
HashMap <String, Parent> criterias = new HashMap <String, Parent>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, parent>>(){}.getType();
String dataCriteria = gson.toJson(criterias, listOfTestObject);
```

In another class I want to retrieve this HashMap:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Parent>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<String, Parent> myMap = gson.fromJson(data, listOfTestObject);
```

The problem is that I want to cast the values of HashMap which are `instanceOf` `Child1` to `Child1`.

And I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Parent cannot be cast to Child1
```

Is there a solution to downcasting?

Comment: Sounds like a case for using `<...,? super Parent>` instead?

Comment: Show us the code part with the `instanceof` and the actual cast.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind : `if( map.get("SomeKey") instanceof Child1){
Child1 mc=(Child1) map.get("SomeKey");}`

Comment: What you've described should work fine, apart from the obvious typos. Can you actually show us some more code, so we can spot your mistake?

Comment: @Unihedron `new Type<>()` give me this error : `The constructor TypeToken<HashMap<String,SearchCriteria>>() is not visible`

Comment: I don't see how this code would be able to throw a ClassCastException. Please edit your question and add the complete exception and show us the line of code which throws the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if you declare your `Map` as follows

```
Map<String , ? super Parent> map = new HashMap<String,Parent>();
```

you'll be able to

- add `Parent`, `Child1`and `Child2` values:

  `map.put( "key" , new Child1() );`
- retrieve these and cast as appropriate

  `Child c1 = (Child1)map.get( "key" );`

The generic part of the map declaration should be read as: Takes anything that is a `Parent` or has `Parent` as a super class.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,

Comment: +1  Although this solution presumably still wouldn't work if you did     map.put( "key" , new Parent() ); Child c1 = (Child1)map.get( "key" );     I'm not sure if this is what Gson is doing under the hood? I guess it's hard to know what the exact problem is until the OP posts his casting code where the exception is being thrown

Comment: @Matt you're right of course. I only meant to point the direction, as the OP - as you state - left out the central part of his problem...

Answer (score 1):

If your object is created with a type Parent there is no way you can downcast in the way you suggest (although this would also mean that `instanceof` would return false, because if an object is `instanceof` `Child1` then you would not get a `ClassCastException` when casting to Child1).

A simple solution is to create a constructor in Parent that takes a Parent object, and essentially clones it (copies over all the fields you are interested in). Then you just override the constructor in your Child classes and call super(parent).

Note this is not super memory-efficient so if this code is going to be in a big loop with millions of entries it's not ideal, but works pretty well.